# Como remover ruidos e linhas de imagem com presença de pelos?

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Estou trabalhando com a remoçao de pelos em imagens de pele. Pesquisando na literatura, os meios para se alcaçar o meu objetivo, se da aplicando algumas tecnicas de segmentação e remoçao de ruidos em imagens. Ao qual estou aplicando. 
Um exemplo de imagem que trabalho é essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aplicando a Diference of de Gaussian na imagem eu tenho a saida:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


#read the input file
img = cv2.imread('014.bmp')

#run a 5x5 gaussian blur then a 3x3 gaussian blr
blur5 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
blur3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),0)

DoGim = blur5 - blur3
cv2.imwrite('014-DoG.jpg', DoGim)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida utilizo o operador morfologico: cv2.morphologyEx para remover os ruidos da imagem, deixando somente os pelos, para que possa, posteriormente, aplicar uma mascara para remoçao desses pelos. Porem, a saida tanto para o `cv2.morphologyEx(img2gray,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)` como `cv2.morphologyEx(img2gray,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)` nao atendem a expecitativa.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

pic = cv2.imread('014DoG.jpg')
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(pic, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Remove hair with opening
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img2gray,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)
plt.imshow(opening, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Open:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Close:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem pode me ajudar a remover estes ruidos e conseguir remover os pelos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você já está usando operações morfológicas, por que não usar diretamente um fechamento para eliminar os pelos?

Você vai precisar saber mais ou menos a grossura média deles para a geração do elemento estruturante, ou pode deixar esse valor configurável no seu sistema. De todas as formas, eu sugiro utilizar uma cruz ao invés de um retângulo pois ele elimina os pelos enquanto que mantém uma maior conexão de "istmos" entre as pintas (no resultado posterior, da limiarização).

Aliás, eu estou supondo que seu interesse é detectar as áreas das pintas, por isso inclui também um exemplo simples de limiarização (thresholding). Estou usando o valor médio da escala de cinza (127), mas você pode precisar fazer um ajuste fino dependendo das suas imagens.

Eis o código (leio a sua própria imagem do disco, chamada de teste.png aqui no meu exemplo):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

pic = cv2.imread('teste.png')
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(pic, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Remove hair with closing and blur
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(10,10))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img2gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
closing = cv2.GaussianBlur(closing, (5, 5), 0)

# Thresholding for the skin patches
_,threshold = cv2.threshold(closing, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

fig = plt.figure('Deteção de Pintas')

plt.subplot(131)
plt.title('Imagem original')
plt.imshow(img2gray, cmap='gray')

plt.subplot(132)
plt.title('Resultado do Fechamento')
plt.imshow(closing, cmap='gray')

plt.subplot(133)
plt.title('Resultado da Limiarização')
plt.imshow(threshold, cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

P.S.: Se o resultado da limiarização não estiver bom o suficiente (mesmo que seja para ser usado como máscara), você pode tentar uma abordagem diferente com o KMédias: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d1/d5c/tutorial_py_kmeans_opencv.html
Utilize 3 (ou 4) agrupamentos (clusters), por exemplo, e jogue fora só os pixels do agrupamento mais claro, mantendo os pixels originais dos outros dois agrupamentos mais escuros.